# R - regd package depended on another package

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a few of my own custom functions that I use a lot into a package that I can use repeatedly using `package.skeleton`. My functions depend on other packages (e.g. `zoo`, `reshape`, `boot`, etc.). For example, suppose I wrote all my custom functions in a file called `myOwnFunctions.R` which resembles as follows:

---

```
myFunc1<-function() { 
   require(zoo) 
   ...
}
myFunc2<-function() { 
   require(boot)
   ...
}
...
myFuncN<-function() { 
  require(reshape)
  ...
}
```

---

where each function has a line with the `require()` function if it uses another library. I converted the file into my own package using the following code below (`createPackage`) that I adopted from 3-4 others posts on StackOverflow (this is actually NOT relevant to my question, but I'm providing it just in case).

```
createPackage<-function (rCodeFile) {
  source(rCodeFile)

  # name the package as the same name as rCodeFile, but remove the path
  pkgName<-strsplit(rCodeFile,"/")[[1]]
  pkgName<-strsplit(pkgName[length(pkgName)],"\\.")[[1]][1]

  # remove existing directory of files that package.skeleton creates
  pkgDir<-paste(getwd(),pkgName,sep="/")
  if (file.exists(pkgDir)) unlink(pkgDir,recursive=TRUE)

  # create a skeleton directory for package
  package.skeleton(name=pkgName)

  # remove the data directory
  unlink(paste(pkgDir,"data",sep="/"),recursive=TRUE)

  # remove files in man directory, except the ones with the name as package
  for (i in list.files(paste(pkgDir,"man",sep="/"))) {
    if (length(grep("package",i))==0) unlink(paste(pkgDir,"man",i,sep="/"))
  }

  # build the package
  system(paste("rcmd","build",pkgName,sep=" "))

  # install the package
  system(paste("rcmd INSTALL -l",paste0("\"",.libPaths()[1],"\""),pkgName,sep=" "))
}
```

As such it works fine, but there is ONE issue. If I call `library(myOwnFunctions)`, then it DOES NOT load `zoo`, `reshape`, etc. at that time, but instead loads `zoo`, `reshape` the first time I call a function that has a `require(zoo)` or `require(reshape)` line etc.

I would like the dependency packages to load when I call `library(myOwnFunctions)`. My question is, instead of using `require` within each of my custom functions `myFunc1`, `myFunc2`, etc., if I write my source code `myOwnFunctions.R` as follows:

---

```
library(zoo)
library(reshape)
library(boot)
...
myFunc1<-function() { 
   ...
}
myFunc2<-function() { 
   ...
}
...
myFuncN<-function() { 
   ...
}
```

---

and then if I run `package.skeleton`, where (i.e. which file? in which folder?) among all the files/directories that `package.skeleton` creates does it incorporate that this package will have a dependency on `zoo`, `reshape`, `boot` etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the DESCRIPTION file created by `package.skeleton`, especially the `Depends` and `Imports` fields.